# Parsing the HTMLImageElement Object

Tags: javascript, object, ionic-framework

I want to show images but I am getting [object HTMLImageElement].How can I get images from [object HTMLImageElement].

Thanks in advance.

html code:

```
<div id = "test" ng-model="newpost.text" placeholder="Enter text here..." class="jjhtext" ng-keypress="restrictKeyPressJJH()" contenteditable = "true"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <a class="tab-item" ng-click="showstickers()">
            <i class="icon ion-happy"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 5px;">
      <span style="margin-left: 200px;">{{300 - newpost.text.length}} left</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is js code:

```
$scope.getStickername = function(sticker){
  if($scope.newpost.text === undefined){
      $scope.newpost.text = " ";
  }
  console.log("sticker name"+sticker.sticker_name);
  console.log("sticker img"+sticker.sticker_img);

          var oImg=document.createElement("IMG"); 
          oImg.src=sticker.sticker_img; 
          oImg.setAttribute("height", "20");
          oImg.setAttribute("width", "15");
          oImg.setAttribute("alt", "Smiley");
          console.log(typeof(oImg));
          console.log(JSON.stringify(oImg));
         $scope.newpost.text = document.getElementById("test").appendChild(oImg);

console.log($scope.newpost.text);


}
```

Comment: Please can you show us the code you have already?

Comment: Please put it in your question , it's easier to read that way.

Comment: in the above code, it store the content in database as htmlimageelement object, how to retrieve the content?

Comment: Are you trying to append a child to a node or override the content of the node?

Comment: yes, i m trying to append the <img> tag with the content of the div.

Comment: Where in the DOM tree would you like it to be appended? Inside the 'test' div, inside the row? Inside the column?

Comment: I am building a chat application, and here the "test" div is working as a textarea, in which input may be text or images or both, like whats app. But with my own stickers, which are shown when user clicks on the icon.